# How to open new terminal window in previous directory using fish shell?

Tags: gnome-terminal, fish

I use fish shell and Gnome-Terminal Version 3.44.

When I open a new terminal I'd like it to start up in the previously-visited directory. How can I implement this via fish shell?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How would you do this in any shell? That's not rhetorical. You'll need to modify your shell environment to save the CWD and read the saved value when starting a new shell.

Comment: Do you want the chronologically most recent directory? How do you define that if you run multiple shells in parallel? Or do you want to open the new (second or subsequent) terminal in the directory where your current terminal's fish resides? If the latter, you need to emit the OSC 7 escape sequence whenever you change directory.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if this sounded vague. By default my previous ubuntu / gnome terminal  automatically opened the last directory i was located in, but this functionality went away when i updated to latest ubuntu so was trying to get back to that default functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options as to when to save the directory:

- When you exit the shell
- Or each time the directory changes

I'll use the "each time" approach for this example.  First, I recommend exiting all but one terminal/fish shell.  This will allow subsequent shell invocations to load the new function properly.

Create a Fish script that runs at startup:

`~/.config/fish/conf.d/starting_dir.fish`:

```
set -q fish_most_recent_dir && [ -d "$fish_most_recent_dir" ] && cd "$fish_most_recent_dir"

function save_dir --on-variable PWD
    set -U fish_most_recent_dir $PWD
end
```

This will:

- check that the `fish_most_recent_dir` variable exists, that it refers to an existing directory, and changes to it if so.
- create a `save_dir` function that saves the current directory to the `fish_most_recent_dir` universal variable whenever the directory changes (`--on-variable PWD`).

The `save_dir` event function needs to be forcibly loaded at startup this way because [autoload functions can't handle events](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/845) in fish.

Note that if there are any other `cd` statements in your startup config, they may get executed *after* this function.  If that happens, they'll override this.

If you want to save the working directory only when Fish exits, you would change the event function to use `--on-event fish_exit` instead.

Comment: not sure why but the save_dir func doesn't seem to actually fire when changing directory. I'm testing on WSL Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: just to clarify. this function with --on-variable does not seem to fire ever beyond the very first time.

Comment: @quiltedcomputer Hmm - Also on WSL, but was using the latest release (3.4.1) on (probably Artix).  So I just tested on on Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL with Fish 2.7.1 (the default there), but it's still working for me there as well.  After each directory change, `set --show fish_most_recent_dir` will show the updated directory.  You mention running `gnome-terminal` -- Are you running that on WSLg (Windows 11) or using some other method?  I just added add gnome-terminal, and it looks like the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04 was 3.28.2.  But the function still fires on every cd there as well ...

Comment: @quiltedcomputer Ahh, I left out a critical step that *could* be what you are seeing (although it doesn't *quite* sound like it according to your description).  But try `funcsave save_dir` after creating the function and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand the function needs to be permanently saved. But this solution unfortunately never worked for me. I'm now also testing on Ubuntu 22.04 with fish 3.4.1. In particular, ```set --show fish_most_recent_dir``` produces no output (just an empty newline). When opening a new terminal, it also opens the home directory.

Comment: @quiltedcomputer Yuck.  I'm so sorry for giving you two wrong answers in a row.  I definitely didn't test the previous one well enough.  The previous version (at least for me), works only one time in the *current* shell, and then fails in every new shell after that.  The reason is that autoload functions in fish apparently can't handle events.  At some level, I knew that, but forgot when crafting the original answer.  Try this one.  I've tested it multiple times now, and it's working for me (assuming I copied/pasted everything correctly).  Again, my apologies!

Comment: Thanks, this now works. and thanks for the explanation. It was certainly not obvious to me that autoloaded functions couldn't handle events, so i appreciate this workaround.